# Wait for change in state causing repeated action emit

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable

When my epic responds at the `ofType` point, I then need to wait till `state$.value.foo` becomes `true`. Once it is true, then I want it to get to the `from` which does a fetch and important stuff. I am doing it like this:

```
action$.pipe(
    ofType(START_CONTINUE_SESSION),
    concat(
        iif(
            () => state$.value.foo === true,
            EMPTY,
            action$.pipe(
                filter(() => state$.value.foo === true),
            )
        ),
        from(fetch(...)).pipe(
            // ... do important stuff here BUT only after state$.value.foo has become true
        )
    )
)
```

What is happening is that I get super high amounts of actions emitted and it never gets to the `from(fetch))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the `concat` operator is deprecated in RxJS 6 (that would be the one imported from `rxjs/operators`). However, the function `concat`, used to create an observable, is *not* deprecated (that would be the one imported from `rxjs`). I would recommend looking to use operators that are not deprecated.

Second, There are several issues with your current approach.

```js
action$.pipe(
  ofType(START_CONTINUE_SESSION),
  concat(
    ...
```

The above filters actions matching type "START_CONTINUE_SESSION" *and allows them to pass back to the Redux store*. This is because the `concat` operator lets the source events to pass through and waits for the previous observable to complete *before* beginning the next observables. However, because the redux-observable action stream never completes, the `concat` *should* never begin the next observables! Check out the following marble diagram from the old RxJS docs:

[image: marble diagram for concat operator]

As the diagram shows, the source events pass through. With redux-obserable, this means your "START_CONTINUE_SESSION" action would be stuck in a never ending, repeating loop.

Even if the action stream ended and the `concat` were to begin the next observables, there are additional issues:

```js
  ...
  iif(
    () => state$.value.foo === true,
    EMPTY, // I've assumed that this is equivalent to `empty()`
    action$.pipe(
      filter(() => state$.value.foo === true),
    ),
  ),
  ...
```

You're first checking the current value of `foo` in the store. If its value is `true`, nothing more is emitted (in just this particular step) and the `from` will begin next. If its value is `false`, a new action stream subscription is created. For every future action dispatched, this checks the current value of `foo` in the store. When its value is finally made `true`, the action that flowed in (which could be any action!) is *allowed to pass back out to the Redux store*. But note, this subscription never ends! You would, again, have a never ending loop of actions coming in and going right back out to the Redux store, so long as `foo` remains `true`.

---

Instead of subscribing to `action$` and checking the state, you should subscribe to `state$`. The following example is a little bit different, but I think it shows a way of accomplishing your goal. This waits for the initial action (`START_CONTINUE_SESSION`), then waits for state to have `foo === true`, then sends both the action and state to a `mergeMap` where you can process it like normal (fetch, dispatch other actions, etc.). If you don't need a copy of state, then that could just be disregarded.

```js
export const epic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(START_CONTINUE_SESSION),
    withLatestFrom(state$),
    exhaustMap(([action, state]) =>
      state.foo === true
        ? of([action, state])
        : state$.pipe(
            mergeMap(state =>
              state.foo === true
                ? of([action, state])
                : empty()
            ),
            first(),
          )
    ),
    mergeMap(([action, state]) =>
      // here we have triggering action and state with foo === true
      from(fetch(...)).pipe(
        // ... do important stuff here
      )
    ),
  )
```

As far as responding to the initial action (`START_CONTINUE_SESSION`), I chose `exhaustMap` in the above example. Possible alternatives include `concatMap`, `mergeMap`, and `switchMap`. You should pick the operator that best fits your use case:

- `concatMap` - Listen for all actions and run multiple workflows sequentially.
- `exhaustMap` - Listen for the first action and wait until you complete the workflow before accepting another action.
- `mergeMap` - Listen for all actions and run multiple workflows in parallel.
- `switchMap` - Listen for all actions but only run one at a time. Cancels any previous workflow when receiving a new action.

Comment: Thank you very much for this, lots to learn here. The thing though is after getting `START_CONTINUE_SESSION`, it mayyyy already have state of `foo = true`. So it may not have to wait. This code is checking in the next ticks correct? (im just asking to learn, tahts why im doing this project, to learn redux-observables and rxjs :) )

Comment: Is the `import { concat }` from `rxjs` depreacated or the one from `rxjs/operators` deperecated?

Comment: Your list on the maps is suuuuper helpful thank you!! Does workflow mean body of that `*Map` or the body plus everything after it?

Comment: I really appreciate your code, but can you please help me understand why my code was doing what it was? That will help me learn a lot. The first `ofType` is waiting for an action `START_CONTINUE_SESSION` then it continues synhronously to check value of `foo` and if its true then it moves onto the `mergeMap` after it, if its false then it waits for next action, and if `foo` is true now, then it should continue to `mergeMap`, why is it repeatedly emitting actions, my mind is boggled there.

Comment: @Noitidart I just made a (big) edit that tries to address all of your comments/questions. You made a good note-- I was providing an alternative solution but not describing why your code wasn't working as you intended. I hope this edit helps make it clear!

Comment: Oh wow thank you so much for this detailed answer!! This is awesome, things are starting to make sense.

Comment: I've been re-reading this quite a bit. A question please, by "waits for the previous observable to complete" what does this mean? Does complete mean the observable has reached the redux reducers? I'm really super greatful for this post of yours, I'm still trying to grasp reading marble diagram, I hope to get there soon! Your words above I think got me there I just need to re-read it a bit more.

Comment: @Noitidart No, I mean it in the strict observable definition sense. Completing a stream is an explicit stream notification (see the third callback of the `subscribe` method). For example, `of(1)` is an observable that will "next" the value 1 and then "complete". The `action$` stream _never_ completes (that's how redux-observable works). Because it never sends a "complete" notification, something that waits on a "complete" notification, like the obsolete `concat` operator, will wait indefinitely.

Comment: Just for learning here, if I did put after the second ation stream an `EMPTY` (in palce of `NOTHING HERE` (in following snippet at end of this comment), would it end that second action stream and move onto the `from`? So instead of `action$.pipe(filter(() => state$.value.foo === true), NOTHING_HERE)),from(...)` If I did `action$.pipe(filter(() => state$.value.foo === true), EMPTY)),from(...)`?

Comment: @Noitidart I'm having a hard time understanding that question given the limited comment formatting. Maybe post this into a new question? _I think_ that still doesn't work because it doesn't end the outer, just the inner. I think you'd want to look at a hack that chains `first()` and `ignoreElements()`. Again, a new question is probably a better place to answer this.

Comment: New question totally makes sense, code in the comment is messy. I'll try some stuff out and definitely throw up a question and at you if I do. Thanks man!